# What unit does the docker run "--memory" option expect?

Tags: docker

I'd like to constrain the memory of a Docker container to 1 GB. According to the documentation, we can specify the desired memory limit using the `--memory` option:

```
$ docker run --memory <size> ...
```

However, the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#parent-command) *does not describe the format or units* for the argument anywhere on the page:

> --memory , -m           Memory limit

What units should I supply to `--memory` and other related options like `--memory-reservation` and `--memory-swap`? Just bytes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Classic case of RTFM on my part. The `--memory` option supports a unit suffix so we don't need to calculate the exact byte number:

> ```
>  -m, --memory=""
>       Memory limit (format: <number>[<unit>], where unit = b, k, m or g)
>
>    Allows you to constrain the memory available to a container. If the
>    host supports swap memory, then the -m memory setting can be larger
>    than physical RAM. If a limit of 0 is specified (not using -m), the
>    container's memory is not limited. The actual limit may be rounded up
>    to a multiple of the operating system's page size (the value would be
>    very large, that's millions of trillions).
> ```

So, to start a container with a 1 GB memory limit as described in the question, both of these commands will work:

```
$ docker run --memory 1g ... 
$ docker run --memory 1073741824 ...
```

The `--memory-reservation` and `--memory-swap` options also support this convention.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-%20access-to-memory):

> Limit a container’s access to memory Docker can enforce hard memory
>   limits, which allow the container to use no more than a given amount
>   of user or system memory, or soft limits, which allow the container to
>   use as much memory as it needs unless certain conditions are met, such
>   as when the kernel detects low memory or contention on the host
>   machine. Some of these options have different effects when used alone
>   or when more than one option is set.
>
> Most of these options take a positive integer, followed by a suffix of
>   `b`, `k`, `m`, `g`, to indicate bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, or gigabytes.

[This page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#specify-hard-limits-on-memory-available-to-containers--m-memory) also includes some extra information about memory limits when running docker on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker run -m 50m <imageId> <command...>
```

This is how it should be given. This forces the docker container to use 50m of memory. As soon as it tries to use more than that, it will be shut down.

However using free -m you won't be able to see anything related to the container memory usage. you have to go inside it to see allowed memory.